# Crystal Report Sum of all Fields by Date

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

So I have a fields that group already by Date (each day). but I want the fields to be summarized. for example below

[Crystal Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Ejn.jpg)

TIA

Comment: create a running total, by group

Answer (score 0):

Take one more group for the column 2 as shown in image and summarized every field in group 2 footer and final total in group 1